# Display Best Selling Products

Tags: magento2, product, sales-order, reports, best-seller

I want replacement of the following code in Magento 2.x

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Bestseller extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc'); // most best sellers on top
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

    $products->setPageSize(3)->setCurPage(1);
    $this->setProductCollection($products);
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to display best selling products in magento2 ?

Comment: Similar to them but I want to use my own query to get product by order_qty descending .